# Displaying output of subshell in parent process

Tags: bash, shell

```
echo "echo in parent process"

bash

echo "echo in subshell"

exit
```

When I execute this code block form terminal (`./test.sh`)

I only see "echo in parent process" as output, but I also want to see the output that coming from subshell. What is the way to see the outputs that coming from subshell/child process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You never see the second command because it hasn't happened yet. Instead, you're just starting bash again, interactively. You'll note you're inside an inner shell now if you type `exit` manually.

```
$ ./test.sh 
echo in parent process
$ exit
echo in subshell
```

What you probably mean to do is:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "echo in parent process"
bash -c 'echo "echo in child process"'
```

Comment: The lines between "bash" and "exit" is running in a child process am I right?

Comment: @MehmetMertYidiran in your original code? No. The shell has to fork/exec to launch the inner `bash` command, but the `echo` following it is a command to the original script, not to the subshell.

Comment: With your information I understand my problem. In Python I used: `output,error  = Popen.communicate()` for subprocess to get output from subprocess.